# country based shipping module in opencart 2.1

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I want to create module or extension, in which i want following feature.

1- when user come from new york and amount more than 500$ then he can get free shipping, i mean there will be a radio button add in delivery step.
2- when user come out side new york and amount more than 700$ then can get free shipping.

But i don't know how can i do it, i also try to do using coupon code module but there is not link between zone and coupon code. Can any one please guide me regarding this module. I would like to appreciate

Comment: You need to create a shipping module , in which you can handle these pricing things

Comment: Shipping method is depend upon Zone. You can set Geo Zone for free shipping according to zone.